# cosmos pagination is not working with latest springboot libraries

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, azure-cosmosdb

We have a springboot project which is using cosmos libraries and the pageable feature of it. It was working as expected. Now, after upgrading the springboot to 3.X.X version, the pagination feature is not working.

We always get the last 3 data even though we pass diff page.

```
public interface BaseRepository extends CosmosRepository<Base, String>, CrudRepository<Base, String> {

    @Query("select * from c where c.base=@baseId)")
    Page<Base> findByBaseId(
        @Param("baseId") String baseId,
        Pageable pageable);
}
```

This the code that we are using, it was giving expected result based on the page number passed in the Paegable object. but now, it always return the latest X number data.

This is how we are initialising the Pageable :

```
PageRequest of(int page, int size, Sort sort)
```

I dont see any reasons why it shopped working? Any pointers?

Comment: What was your version before? When it was working.

Comment: the previous version is : 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Spring Data Cosmos **does not support Spring Boot 3 or Spring Data 3** -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/30458

That is potentially the reason it is not working as expected when you migrated from 2.7.6 to 3.X (major version bump).

Comment: I am not sure why but after replacing the azure-spring-data-cosmos with spring-cloud-azure-starter-data-cosmos, the pagination also started working fine. But the point is that after looking at this response that the support for spring 3 is not available, I am not sure what to do? shall we proceed or shall we postpone this task.

Comment: Based on that GitHub issue, I don't see a guarantee that it is fully supported, see the last comment on the issue -> "We are now targeting H1 this year (by end of June 2023) to support Cosmos DB in Spring Boot 3."